# Renaming filename and set content approval status - power automate

Tags: power-automate, content-approval

I have a requirement to build an approval workflow so i switched on content approval for the document library.
It all works well in power automate as i can use the "Set content approval status"
But one other requirement is to be able to use a word template when creating files in the document library and then rename the file accordingly based on some metadata.

My problem is i'm using the "Send HTTP Request" to change the file name like so
[image]

Bu when my flow gets to the "Set content approval status" it fails

[image]

The reason I think is because of the Etag since i have renamed the file.
I get the Etag by using the Get file metadata
[image]

[image]

Any ideas what I need to do after renaming a file so i ca set content approval status?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What happens when you do not pass any value to ETag?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I managed to figure it out. I had to use etag when using "set content approval".
What worked is i used the "Get File properties" first and then the "Get file  Metadata".
After doing this it worked

Comment: From which action outputs you used ETag, Get file properties or get file metadata?

Comment: Get File Properties Etag is used in Get file metadata and then the Etag is used in the set content approval.
Hope this helps